# How can make screen reader reads an error on a field with multiple options?

Tags: forms, checkbox, radio-button, accessibility

I'm using jQuery Validation Plugin and it returns a label with the error message, but on multiple radios or checkboxes, how can I return the error message to screen readers and make it read the message when the user focus on the options?

```
<fieldset class="label">
    <legend>Revistas<em>*</em></legend>
    <div class="fields">
        <input type="checkbox" id="field_revista_veja" class="checkbox required" name="revista" title="Veja" />
        <label for="field_revista_veja">Veja</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" id="field_revista_epoca" class="checkbox" name="revista" title="Época" />
        <label for="field_revista_epoca">Época</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" id="field_revista_galileu" class="checkbox" name="revista" title="Galileu" />
        <label for="field_revista_galileu">Galileu</label>
    </div>
    <label id="?" generated="true" class="error">Error: Choose one of the options at least</label>
</fieldset>
```

The screen reader reads each checkbox but it cannot see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

First, have you actually tested what you have yet? If so, with what browser and screenreader? Versions?

Try putting aria-live="assertive" on the label. You may have to find a way to put focus on the label too, maybe by adding a link inside it.

It also depends on what screenreader you are testing in. NVDA with Firefox will handle ARIA better than IE with an old version of JAWS.